# I dont understand this TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can somebody see the problem? I think I am passing three parameters in frompoints function not four right?

```
class vector2D:

    def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return "({}, {})".format(self.x, self.y)

    @classmethod
    def frompoints(cls, P1, P2):
        x = P2[0] - P1[0]
        y = P2[1] - P1[1]
        return vector2D(cls, x, y)

P1 = (10.0, 5.0)
P2 = (17.0, 10.0)
v2 = vector2D.frompoints(P1, P2)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/Pycharm/Testy/test.py", line 22, in <module>
v2 = vector2D.frompoints(P1, P2)
File "D:/Pycharm/Testy/test.py", line 17, in frompoints
return vector2D(cls, x, y)
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cls` argument in a `@classmethod` is *the class itself*, in this case `vector2D`. You don't pass the class as an argument elsewhere (it's not `vector2D(vector2D, x, y)`), so why do it here?

What might be confusing you is that you can call instance methods on the class and explicitly pass an instance as the first argument:

```
vector2D.__init__(instance, x, y)
```

However, `frompoints` is a class method, so you don't yet *have* an instance to pass. You should be doing:

```
return cls(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass cls argument while creating new object.
So instead of: `return vector2D(cls, x, y)` you should do this: `return vector2D(x, y)`

Comment: This will cause subtle errors if called in a class inheriting from `vector2D` - the point of the `cls` argument is that it's the class, so you can do `return cls(x, y)`.

Comment: The `cls` approach is likely to cause more problems than it's worth.  Consider the case where I define a `Vector3D` that inherits from `Vector2D` and adds an additional constructor parameter `z`.  Invoking `frompoints` on the `Vector3D` subclass will fail unless it's explicitly overridden.

Comment: @BrettLempereur isn't it worse if it explicitly calls `vector2D(x, y)` and isn't overridden? Then you quietly get back a 2D vector from your pair of 3D points. I would argue that the `TypeError` from `vector3D.__init__` is a better outcome, as it actually tells you something's wrong.